# apache2 Webdav using VirtualDocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, webdav

I'm trying to get up **dynamical** WebDav on my virtual hosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # http://www.example.com/test.txt -> /var/www/example.com/www/test.txt
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-2.0.%-1.0/%-3+/ 

    <Location /webdav>
        Dav On
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "example.com"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/[PROBLEM-1]/passwd.dav

        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

1. Is there any way I can set dynamically **PROBLEM-1** placeholder based on whatever comes with *HTTP_HOST*? More precisely part of it? Example:

   - HTTP_HOST = www.example.com -> PROBLEM-1 = example.com
   - HTTP_HOST = example.com -> PROBLEM-1 = example.com

What I'm trying to do here is to load dav passwd file dynamically based on which domain is requested. It is something like "groups" if you wish. So that owner of domainA is not allowed to access files of domainB. So maybe there is some other solution based on **AuthGroupFile** directive? Or anything based on LDAP authentication which would use groups named after hosts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do that, but I think you should be able to use an .htaccess file to accomplish the same thing.